# Find out which menu an article is assigned to

Tags: articles

Does anybody know a way to find out which menu item an article is attached to in Joomla 3.x ?
When you open a menu item you can see which article is attached to that menu. But the opposite  is not shown. How can I see which menu(s) an article is attached to?

Answer (score 1):

To get menu items assigned to specific article, where `$articleId` is the article ID:

```
$assignedItems = array();

// Get all Articles component menu items.
$menuItems = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu('site')->getItems('component', 'com_content');

foreach ($menuItems as $menuItem)
{
    // Check that menu item is for article view and that IDs match.
    if ($menuItem->query['view'] === 'article' && $menuItem->query['id'] == $articleId)
    {
        $assignedItems[] = $menuItem;
    }
}
```

There's a simpler way but it doesn't account for different layouts, if any, and additional menu item URL parameters that might be added by plugins:

```
$assignedItems = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu('site')->getItems('link', 'index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=' . $articleId);
```

The rest depends on where and how exactly you want to display the items.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I was wondering if there is a way to do this in administrator page. I don't even know where and how to use this code..

Comment: Which page? Article form?